# In the Grails configuration how do I access variables in other environments?

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler, config

If I have a list environment variable in grails in one environment, how do I modify it on the cascade to other environments?

For instance, in my quartz configuration I added the following,

```
quartz {
    // other variables remove for clarity

    whiteListedJobs = [ Job1.class, Job2.class, Job3.class ]
}
```

The quartz is not specific to any single environment. But in my environment specific configurations I'd like to override this list to include more jobs for certain environments.

Something like,

```
environments {
    development {
        quartz {
            whiteListedJobs = whiteListedJobs + Job4.class
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. My code that tries to read the quartz config variable as a list throws `Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.util.List'`, which suggests to me that it isn't working.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the groovy `ConfigSlurper` doesn't provide a way to read a config entry at a different level during the parsing process. However, it is parsed as a Groovy script, so you can use local variables to avoid completely rewriting entries:

```
def defaultJobs = [ Job1.class, Job2.class, Job3. class ]
quartz {
    whiteListedJobs = defaultJobs
}

environments {
    development {
        quartz {
            whiteListedJobs = defaultJobs + Job4.class
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Will that defaultJobs variable be cleaned up properly?

Comment: I'm not positive what you mean by that, but as it is a local variable to the Config script, it goes out of scope after parsing and is not included in the config object. (eg. `grailsApplication.config.defaultJobs` will not be populated)